# How to resolve a OutOfMemory finding from MAT Analyzer in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, out-of-memory

I am getting OutOfMemory Exception in my app. I have taken the heap dump and analyzed through MAT. While analyzing my app memory usage I found following suspect. I am unable to understand the main cause behind these suspects.

How can I understand these leakage suspects:

> **Problem Suspect 1**
>
> The thread org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread  ajp-apr-8109-exec-1 keeps local variables with total size 825,693,992 (56.23%) bytes.
>
> The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread" loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader8".
>   The stacktrace of this Thread is available. See stacktrace.
>
> Keywords
>   java.net.URLClassLoader org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread
>
> **Problem Suspect 2**
>
> The thread org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread ajp-apr-8109-exec-3 keeps local variables with total size 556,977,328 (37.93%) bytes.
>
> The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread" loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @".
>   The stacktrace of this Thread is available. See stacktrace.

Comment: Is it a real problem? I mean, is the memory usage increasing over time, without GC freeing enough memory? I couldn't find source code for BaseNCDController or DotNetXmlDataSetConverter but I assume you might be loading XML datasets into memory?

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Obviously, GC is still running, and at that time, Full GC was still appearing.

There is a source code or a GC graph, but the clue given so far is uncertain of the cause.

Comment: In case of this, what exactly should you see to know the cause?

Should I check with comprehensive clues? (ex) GC graph, source code, tomcat log ....etc.

I was mistaken that MAT solved everything.

Comment: I mean you should know what your app is doing under the hood. If it's loading a big XML into memory when processing a request then it's completely normal that a thread allocated several hundred megabytes.

Comment: As you said, certain XML is being repeatedly loaded into memory.

DotNetXmlDataSetWriter and DotNetXmlDataSetConverter seem to be the only XML processing.

Comment: In fact, suspect 1 and suspect 2 combined, a specific xml occupied 800 MB of the total 1.4G retained heap.

It is estimated that FullGC occurred during XML processing.

Comment: Beside, The XML dataset is  140 MB when processing a request

Comment: 140 MB may mean much more in terms of heap memory - the min size for an empty String object is 40 bytes